# Any one experienced problem installing (ilog/ibm)'s cplex?

Tags: 11.04, installation, r

this was working on 10.04, but now i can't get it to work again....

cplex seem to be properly installed (though if anyone can suggest a way to insure this is indeed the case, i'd be thankful)

any idea ?

```
CPLEXDIR=/root/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122/cplex
SYSTEM=x86-64_sles10_4.1
LIBFORMAT=static_pic
#COPT  = -m64 -fPIC 
#CFLAGS  = $(COPT)  -I$(CPLEXINCDIR)
CPLEXLIBDIR=$CPLEXDIR/lib/$SYSTEM/$LIBFORMAT
#CLNFLAGS  = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -lcplex -lm -pthread

 R CMD INSTALL \
    --configure-args="--with-cplex-include=$CPLEXLIBDIR \
    --with-cplex-cflags=-fPIC \
    --with-cplex-lib='-L$CPLEXLIBDIR/static_pic \
    -lcplex -lm -lpthread'" ~/Documents/Rcplex_0.3-0.tar.gz

* installing to library ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12’
* installing *source* package ‘Rcplex’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking ilcplex/cplex.h usability... no
checking ilcplex/cplex.h presence... no
checking for ilcplex/cplex.h... no
configure: error: CPLEX header cplex.h not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rcplex’
* removing ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/Rcplex’
```

however, when i check

```
cd cd /root/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122/cplex/include/ilcplex
ls
cplex.h  ilm.h  ilocarray.h  ilocplex.h  ilocplexi.h  iloextrmgr.h  ilogoals.h  solution.xsd  solution.xsl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for the records. the [guide](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL) says to substitute CPLEXDIR by whatever is 
found after  CFLAGS in the Make files which in our case is

```
/root/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122/cplex
```

not quiet right. It used to be so, but now it is:

```
/root/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_AcademicResearch122/cplex/include
```

fix that in the code above and it flies.